# Como alterar o cache do google para site reformulado

Tags: google, seo

Existe um site aonde as suas opções estão nos resultados de pesquisa do Google, só que acontece que o site foi todo reformulado, assim como também as suas opções e conteúdos.

Quando a pesquisa é realizada, aparecem as informações do antigo site no resultado do google e não do novo.

Como faço para alterar os resultados?

Comment: Um dos melhores jeitos é manter o _sitemap_ atualizado, e usar as ferramentas para _webmaster_ do google pra deixar tudo em dia. Reenviar o site pode ajudar, se o Google não mudou de novo as regras do jogo. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

Comment: Obrigado vou fazer as verificações do google.

Answer (score 6):

Se com cache você quer dizer as páginas indexadas pelo *Google* que ficam como cópias por exemplo:

> [image: Cache google]

O Google não atualiza ou indexa imediatamente as páginas quando você faz uma atualização no site, o máximo que ele faz é recolher o conteúdo e agendar pra prepara-lo, isto pode levar semanas ou meses, depende de quantas visitas ou o rank do site e não tem como "controlar" ou forçar o Google reindexar.

Não tem como afirmar o tempo em média, o *Google* vive mudando, hoje eles fazem de uma maneira e amanhã pode ser de outra.

Essas páginas de "cache" ao qual se refere que aparecem junto ao resultado de busca levam algum tempo pra atualizarem, assim como com a indexação.

### Redirecionamento de links antigos

Se os links que aparecem no cache são antigos e mudaram de estrutura, por exemplo:

```
http://examplo/siteantigo/?pag=produto&id=1
```

E agora ele é acessado assim:

```
http://examplo/sitenovo/produto/1
```

Uma boa estratégia é reaproveitar links antigos já indexados, claro que não é garantido, vai depender do rank do link especifico dentro de um determinado site. Para reaproveitar e até aportantar para páginas que representam o mesmo conteúdo de páginas especificas será necessário fazer um redirecionamento permanente pelo HTTP, por exemplo criar um script assim em `siteantigo/index.php`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['pag'], $_GET['id'])) {
    /* Isto direciona para: http://exemplo/sitenovo/{pagina}/{id} */
    header('Location: /sitenovo/' . $_GET['pag'] . '/' . $_GET['id'], false, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Claro que isso é só um exemplo pra explicar o redirecionamento, não tem uma formula pronta, vai depender de como você fez o site antigo e como você fez o novo, se forem tecnologias conhecidas como Joomla ou Wordpress é provável que existam plugins pra isto, mas isto é bastante amplo.

Note que se você não fizer o redirecionamento de URLs antigas é provável que no painel [Google/webmaster](http://Google/webmaster) comece a aparecer uma série de erros *Not found* ou o *Soft 404*, o *Soft 404* ocorre quando a página emite outro código como o 200, mas a página retorna uma resposta vazia, ou uma página que não parece ter conteúdo (o Google consegue identificar mesmo que a página tenha menus e rodapé, mas não tenha um razoável conteúdo ou tenha uma mensagem de erro talvez).

### META tag revisit-after

Até existe uma tag `<meta>` que deveria ser usada pra isto, seria a `revisit-after`, por exemplo, visitar a cada 15 dias:

```
<meta name="revisit-after" content="15 days">
```

Você poderia colocar 1 dia, mas o Google geralmente desconsidera, pois muitas pessoas usam isto pra tentar manter atualizado e no entanto a taxa de atualização era bem baixa ou demorada e isto seria péssimo pra eles se todos sites do mundo quisessem atualizações de 1 dia, portanto eles analisam o trafego feito através de "buscas" e eles calculam quais precisam de maior atualização ao invés de usar o valor da tag que você definir.

Conforme este link https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Utilizando_meta_tags na verdade é o uso de `revisit-after` deve ser pra servidores proxy.

### Sitemap.xml

Você pode usar as tags:

- `<priority>` pra determinar a importância da página.
- `<lastmod>` define a data da ultima atualização.

Mas note que isso não é garantia de agilizar indexação ou renovação do cache. Se necessita forçar remover uma URL você pode usar a tag `<expires>` pra remover urls que não deseja mais, exemplo:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://www.examplo.com/expired.html</loc>
    <expires>2011-06-21</expires>
</url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o link abaixo para solicitar ao Google que atualize o cache do seu site nas pesquisas:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

Espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score -1):

**Siga os passsos abaixo:**

- Para colocar seu site na fila prioritária de espera você deve
  primeiro criar uma conta no Google Search e adicionar o seu site lá.
  Siga os passos nesse [link][1]

  [1]: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=pt-BR
- Após isso vai no sidebar do lado esquerdo e procure um menu chamado
  "inspeção de URL", click nele e coloque a URL do seu site. Exemplo "huebr.com.br"
- Após a inspeção aparecerá um relatório do seu site, caso tenha algum erro o Google mostrará o porquê.
- Após corrigir o erro se houver, faça uma nova solicitação de indexação, para fazer isso basta clicar em "Solicitar indexação"

Lembre-se! leva uma tempo até que seu site seja indexado novamente, então seja paciente. No meu caso leva em média só 10min, mas tem casos que lavam até 2 dias

Espero ter ajudado!
Att,