# Para que serve isso?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Estou fazendo um curso e não sei absurdamente nada e fiquei em duvida, para que exatamente isso serve?

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: Relacionado [Para que servem as meta tags do HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454939/para-que-servem-as-meta-tags-do-html)

Comment: Cada meta tags podem ser usadas por vários motivos, frameworks, tecnologias, etc.  O nome ser META já diz tudo, elas contêm informações de metadados, tem as que são usadas para SEO, tem as que são usadas para renderização de layout (como a viewport) ou de caracteres, tem as especificas usadas por terceiros. Sobre `<meta name=viewport>` você pode ler em: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag